# putting button inside code

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

My working code outputs all the images in my wordpress post and puts the last image as the background of #last-img which is the last image shown.

I'm trying to place a button inside my code which appears inside the #last-img. I can't put it outside the code since when I tried when I use absolute positioning it uses all the images as a reference point

my code

```
<?php
    preg_match_all('/(<img [^>]*>)/', get_the_content(), $images);
    preg_match_all('/src="([^"]*)"/i', get_the_content(), $images1);
    $count = count($images[1]);
    $count1 = count($images1[1]);
    foreach($images[1] as $k=> $img){
        if($k == $count-1){
            $format = '<div id="last-img" style="background:url(%s)"> ... </div>'; // Or $format = "<div id='last-img' style='background:url(%s)'> ... </div>";
            $image = $images1[1][$count1-1];
            echo sprintf($format,$image);
        }else{
            echo $img;
        }
    }
    ?>
```

link code

```
<div id="top-btn">
  <div id="top-rotate"></div>       
  <a href="..."></a>
</div>
```

css

```
#top-btn { 
display: block;
position: absolute;
z-index: 200;
right: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0;
margin: 0 auto;
height: 60px; width: 60px;
}
```

Comment: provide link your website

Comment: my site is on local server

Comment: then provide screenshot

Comment: Why you did not used echo("<button onclick=\"location.href='YOUR LOCATION'\">YOUR BUTTON NAME</button>"); ??

Comment: I think your misunderstanding my question, I want to physically put the button code inside my php so that I can use css to position the button inside the #last-div. I don't need it to link anywhere specific

Comment: Not 100% I understand exactly your intent - to clarify, do you want the output to be something like: ```<div id="last-img" style="background:url(http://image.url/thing.jpg)"><div id="top-btn"><div id="top-rotate"></div><a href="..."></a></div></div>``` for that last image?

Comment: yes thats the output i'm looking for